OR-Tools bad_alloc exception
I'm trying to solve vehicle routing problem with OR-tools library in python 3.10.12.
With the settings used the solver crashes. I don't understand what the problem is, if I only use one vehicle this doesn't happen.
I have already read this issue (https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3975), even with this command: search_parameters.local_search_operators.use_shortest_path_swap_active = "BOOL_FALSE"
it doesn't work.
ortools Version:
the problem only exists with versions higher than 9.4.1874.
Error throwed
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc Aborted

from typing import List
from google.protobuf import duration_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from datetime import time

class Location:
    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        self.id = id

    def isDepot(self) -> bool:
        return False  # Default implementation returns False
    def isStep(self) -> bool:
        return False  # Default implementation returns False

class Magazzino(Location):
    def __init__(self,  id) -> None:
        super().__init__( 0) 

    def isDepot(self) -> bool:
        return True

class Step(Location):
    def __init__(self, id ,  type, seq_ordine) -> None:
        super().__init__(id )
        self.id_step = id #  step.id_step
        self.id_ordine = 1 # step.id_ordine
        self.tipo_step = type # step.tipo_step
        self.seq_ordine =  seq_ordine # step.seq_ordine
    
    def isStep(self) -> bool:
        return True


class VRPSolver:

    def __init__(self,  steps : List[Step], depots : List[Magazzino] ):
        self.steps = steps

        combined_locations = depots + steps  

        self.step_id_to_index = { loc.id: idx for idx, loc in enumerate(combined_locations) if loc.isStep()}  # Map custom IDs to indices
        self.index_to_obj = {idx: obj for idx , obj in enumerate(combined_locations)}  # Reverse map

        print("STEP_ID_TO_INDEX:" , self.step_id_to_index)

        self.data = {
            'distance_matrix': [[  0,  21, 209, 106, 132, 121],
       [ 21,   0, 220, 127, 122, 128],
       [209, 220,   0, 214, 341, 311],
       [106, 127, 214,   0, 188, 116],
       [132, 122, 341, 188,   0,  94],
       [121, 128, 311, 116,  94,   0]],
            'time_matrix':  [[  0,  19, 193,  98, 122, 112],
       [ 19,   0, 203, 117, 113, 118],
       [193, 203,   0, 198, 315, 287],
       [ 98, 117, 198,   0, 174, 107],
       [122, 113, 315, 174,   0,  87],
       [112, 118, 287, 107,  87,   0]],
            'num_vehicles': 4,
            'depot': 0,
            'vehicle_capacities': [ 100 ] * 4,
            'pickups_deliveries': [],
            'vehicle_constraints' : {}
        }
        # self.vehicle_constraint() # RIMOSSO PERCHé CHIAMATO DAL LOGIC
        self.consequential_constraint()
        print(self.data)

    def consequential_constraint(self):
        order_steps = {}
        for s in self.steps:
            if s.id_ordine not in order_steps:
                order_steps[s.id_ordine] = []
            order_steps[s.id_ordine].append(s)
        
        print("ORDER_STEP",order_steps)
        # Determine pickup and delivery pairs
        for order in order_steps.values():
            pickups = {s for s in order if s.tipo_step == 'R'}
            deliveries = {s for s in order if s.tipo_step == 'C'}
            
            for p in pickups:
                for d in deliveries:
                    if d.seq_ordine  > p.seq_ordine :
                        self.add_pickup_delivery(p.id, d.id)
                        print("PICKUP  : " + str(p.id) + " C : " + str(d.id)) 

    def add_pickup_delivery(self, pickup_id, delivery_id):
        pickup_index =    self.step_id_to_index[pickup_id]
        delivery_index =   self.step_id_to_index[delivery_id]
        self.data['pickups_deliveries'].append([pickup_index, delivery_index])
    
    def solve(self):
        manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
            len(self.data['distance_matrix']), self.data['num_vehicles'], self.data['depot']
        )
        routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

        ##### TIME ######
        def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return self.data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

        time_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

        # Add Time Dimension
        routing.AddDimension(
            time_callback_index,
            60,  # Allow for some waiting time
            30000,  # Large enough to not overly restrict route maximum time
            False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero. This doesn't force the vehicle to start right at the time at the depot
            'Time'
        )
        time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
        time_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(1)  # Adjust this to give time some influence but less than distance

        ###### DISTANCE ######
        def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return self.data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

        transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)


        # Add distance dimension
        routing.AddDimension(
            transit_callback_index, 0, 10000, True, 'Distance'
        )
        distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Distance')
        distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(1)
            
        # Add pickup and delivery
        for request in self.data['pickups_deliveries']:
            pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[0])
            delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[1])
            routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
            routing.solver().Add(
                routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(delivery_index)
            )
            routing.solver().Add(
                distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <= distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index)
            )

        search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
        search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
            routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC  # Less intensive strategy
        )
        search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
            routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.TABU_SEARCH    # Change the metaheuristic
        )
        search_parameters.local_search_operators.use_shortest_path_swap_active = "BOOL_FALSE"

        search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 1  # Limit the search time
        search_parameters.log_search = True  # Enable logging

        solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
        if solution:
            return solution

def main():
    all_magazzini = [ Magazzino(id=0),
                      Magazzino(id=1 )  ]

    all_step = []
    all_step.append(Step(1, 'C', 4))       
    all_step.append(Step(2, 'R', 1))       
    all_step.append(Step(3, 'C', 3))       
    all_step.append(Step(4, 'R', 2))       

    solver = VRPSolver( steps= all_step, depots = all_magazzini  )#  , vehicles = vehicles,   depot=0,  locations=locations)
    sol = solver.solve()
    print(sol)
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I've tried using all versions higher than 9.4, none of them work.
I also tried the proposed solution
search_parameters.local_search_operators.use_shortest_path_swap_active = "BOOL_FALSE"
But nothing change.
metaheuristic
I have tried differents local_search_metaheuristic.

TABU_SEARCH
GREEDY_DESCENT
SIMULATED_ANNEALING


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@СергейКох Here you are

I may have found the problem. the error could be caused by entering different deliveries for the same pickup order.
I need to be able to impose several deliveries on the model following an initial pickup.

The error is caused by entering different deliveries for the same pickup.
By doing this, the latest versions fail to solve the problem, raising the exception described above.
For some reason unknown to me, version 9.4 is able to solve the problem, even though the solution was not optimal.
To overcome this problem it is necessary to duplicate the nodes so that each node is only in 1 P&D pair
